# Transform big file in ASP.NET MVC Controller without saving on disc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csv, stream

Is it possible to transform big file just posted to controller and start download of transformed file without saving files to disc? I would like to read big .CSV file, do some changes in fields and return transformed .CSV as a stream to user who upload initial file. Main problem is that I should not save file to disc. Is is possible to do with help of  or I need to do ajax call?

Comment: Have you tried reading the stream line by line and outputting another stream line by line?

Comment: you can but how big is big - will it cause memory issues if multiple concurrent requests come in to do the same thing?

Comment: File could be up to 500MB. I know it there could be memory problem but this is why I would like to use Streams. I expect that I could read input file line by line and write transformed line to result stream.

Comment: " I know it there could be memory problem but this is why I would like to use Streams"...keeping it all in memory is what would _cause_ a memory problem. Better to write it to disk and then read it line by line. But TBH if you're going to try and upload and download a file of 500MB in one request then realistically you're going to time out your request before you get anywhere near completing it. You'll have to massively increase the asp.net timeout. Even then it's not predictable and you might have issues.

Comment: A web app is not necessarily the best solution to this kind of bulk processing. Must it be done via the web, or could another solution be used? I don't know if you're accepting these files from users from the public internet, or if this is being done within a corporate network where other methods of file transfer and communication may be available.

Comment: @ADyson As far as I know when we use Stream we can read data partially and memory could be used only partially. It is not necessary to load all file in memory, we can work with file line by line and it means size of used memory could be similar to memory of one line of initial file. Of course I understand GC could be executed more frequently.

Comment: "As far as I know when we use Stream we can read data partially and memory could be used only partially" yes, if the rest of the file is stored somewhere else, i.e. on a disk. But in your suggested scenario the entire file is in memory when it's received from the client, and then you're proposing never to save that anywhere (so that you could dispose of the object), so it will remain in memory. Then you're processing it and creating a new version of it to output, so even more memory gets consumed. I don't see what would be problem of using a temporary file for this, you can delete it afterward

Comment: entire file is in HttpPostedFile.InputStream of incomming request

Comment: using temp file should be avoided according to requirements because file contains sensitive data and customer would like to avoid having it on server

Comment: Ok so you're using HttpPostedFile. Good. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx says "By default, all requests, including form fields and uploaded files, larger than 256 KB are buffered to disk, rather than held in server memory." So it saves it to disk for you and then you can stream it. So hopefully that solves that issue. The file should be temporary so concerns about sensitive data shouldn't be a problem. Of course since your file is sensitive I hope you're using HTTPS to transmit it?

Answer (score 0):

Of course. So long as the file is not so huge it will cause memory problems on the server side. Even then, you're OK so long as you can transform the file line by line. In fact, most server file transformations are probably done in memory without writing anything to disk. This has nothing to do with "ajax" BTW, which is purely a term which relates to how the user interface is rendered.

Comment: I'm thinking about details of implementation. I would like to have html form with Submit button and right after submit download of transformed file should start. I know how to do that with help of JavaScrip and Ajax but not sure is it possible to do with just html.

Comment: @AlexKapelyukhovskiy " I know how to do that with help of JavaScrip and Ajax but not sure is it possible to do with just html"...you'd just use a regular HTML form which posts back to the server. Frankly if you already know all about ajax and JS then surely you would know about regular forms? Normally you'd learn that first before complicating things with ajax.

Comment: @ADyson I just want to make solution simpler but not sure is it possible with html form. I saw websites where download was starting and user left on the initail page. Probably it was ajax call.

Comment: @AlexKapelyukhovskiy Uploading via a HTML form and standard postback is much less complicated than ajax, because no javascript code is required. But yes the user is likely to be left on the initial page because the response is a file which goes to the user's disk, and not a HTML page, so there's nothing for the browser to replace the initial page with. As for downloading files, you can't do that via ajax anyway, so that's a non-starter in this scenario.